# Only one div to show on clicking one and the other div if opened should hide

Tags: javascript

Well creating the cards i came across the problem that on clicking the ellipsis(as mentioned below) one div should appear. and on clicking another ellipsis if any div is open then it should collapse or hide.i have tried the following as mentioned below.Hope experts will help me in this regard to tackle the problem.

```js
const ellipsis = document.querySelectorAll(".ellipsis");
ellipsis.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const report = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector(".report");
    report.classList.toggle("show");
  })
)
```

```css
.main{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.card{
  width: 150px;
  height:200px;
  background: coral;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}
.card h4{
  color:#fff;
  top:35%;
  left:40%;
  position:absolute;
}
.card .flag {
  top:0;
  right:15px;
  position:absolute;
}
.flag .report{
  display:none;
  float:left;
  background: #fff;
  padding:0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.flag .report.show{
  display:block;
}
.card .flag button{
  border:0;
  background:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
}
.report p{
 padding: 2px 5px;
  top:-10px;
  font-size:10px;
  line-height:0.1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const ellipsis = document.querySelectorAll(".ellipsis");
ellipsis.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const report = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector(".report");
    if(report.classList.contains("show")){
      closeReports();
    }else{
      closeReports();
      report.classList.add("show");
    }
    function closeReports(){
      document.querySelectorAll(".report").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show"));
    }
  })
)
```

```css
.main{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.card{
  width: 150px;
  height:200px;
  background: coral;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}
.card h4{
  color:#fff;
  top:35%;
  left:40%;
  position:absolute;
}
.card .flag {
  top:0;
  right:15px;
  position:absolute;
}
.flag .report{
  display:none;
  float:left;
  background: #fff;
  padding:0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.flag .report.show{
  display:block;
}
.card .flag button{
  border:0;
  background:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
}
.report p{
 padding: 2px 5px;
  top:-10px;
  font-size:10px;
  line-height:0.1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious means would be to retrieve a collection of all open reports (with the selector `.report.show`), iterate over that collection and close each one in turn, see the example below with explanatory comments:

```js
// retrieving all elements in the document with the class of 'card':
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card'),
  // creating a named function to handle the showing/hiding of the
  // .report element(s), passing in a reference to the Event Object
  // (passed from the later call of EventTarget.addEventListener()):
  toggleReport = (evt) => {
    // from the Event Object we retrieve the '.card' element to
    // which the event-handler was bound, and the 'target' which
    // is the element upon which the event was fired:
    let focusedCard = evt.currentTarget,
      target = evt.target,
      // retrieving the '.report' element within the current 'card':
      report = focusedCard.querySelector('.report');
      
    // if the clicked element matches the supplied CSS selector we
    // go ahead:
    if (target.matches('.ellipsis')) {
      // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all elements
      // within the document that match the supplied selector, and
      // using spread syntax and an Array literal to convert the
      // NodeList to an Array; we then pass that Array to
      // Array.prototype.filter():
      [...document.querySelectorAll('.report.show')].filter(
        // passing in the 'rep' argument to the function body, which
        // is a reference to the current 'report', and retaining
        // only those elements which are not exactly equal to the
        // report we retrieved earlier:
        (rep) => rep !== report
      ).forEach(
        // we then iterate through the remaining elements of the Array,
        // and remove the 'show' class from each:
        (rep) => rep.classList.remove('show')
      );
      
      // on the report within the focusedCard we toggle the 'show'
      // class to show, or hide, it based on its current state:
      report.classList.toggle('show');
    }

  };

cards.forEach(
  (el) => el.addEventListener('click', toggleReport)
);
```

```css
.main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: coral;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.card h4 {
  color: #fff;
  top: 35%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}

.card .flag {
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.flag .report {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.flag .report.show {
  display: block;
}

.card .flag button {
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.report p {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 0.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
      <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
      <div class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        <p>Not-Interested</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
      <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
      <div class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        <p>Not-Interested</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ry4Lv3p1/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: @gagz same is the case, it is not dissappearing on clicking elipsis again

Answer (score 0):

```
const ellipsis = document.querySelectorAll(".ellipsis");
let clickedEl = null;
ellipsis.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (clickedEl) clickedEl.classList.remove("show");
    const report = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector(".report");
    report.classList.toggle("show");
    clickedEl = report;

  })
)
```

Comment: problem is it not dissappearing on clicking the the same elipsis.

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate, remove all .show from any other report that has the class and then toggle the report belonging to the clicked ellipsis.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
main.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('.ellipsis')) return; // leave if not an ellipsis button
  const thisReport = tgt.closest('.flag').querySelector('.report');
  main.querySelectorAll('.report.show')
    .forEach(report =>  report !== thisReport && report.classList.remove('show'));
  thisReport.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
.main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: coral;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.card h4 {
  color: #fff;
  top: 35%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}

.card .flag {
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.flag .report {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.flag .report.show {
  display: block;
}

.card .flag button {
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.report p {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 0.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
      <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
      <div class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        <p>Not-Interested</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
      <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
      <div class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        <p>Not-Interested</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: instead of defining the main div can you define the the const ellipsis and make a function of ellipsis inplace of main, it would be great help.

Comment: I do not understand what you want. By targeting the container ad delegate from it, we simplify the code. What do you mean by defining the main div vs defining the const ellipsis? There should be ONE container and there are MULTIPLE ellipsis elements